# What someone means when says "I'm hiding under my bed" in a conversation?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms

What someone means when says "I'm hiding under my bed" in a conversation?

I heard someone said this sentence in a political conversation, I did a little search but didn't find something that comes across, could it mean that "I'm going to avoid talking about it"? or that "I don't think about it"?

Comment: What was the context? Did the political discussion include mentions of LGBT people, since they're said to be "in the closet" when they're hiding their LGBT status?

Comment: @nick012000 No that wasn't LGBT, a guy said "the US killed more than 2 million innocent Iraqis in its phony war..." (in an American website) and an American guy answered to that comment so.

Comment: It looks to me like a not-particularly-common metaphoric usage corresponding to ***I'm hiding behind the sofa**!* in my neck of the woods. Or less fancifully, ***I'm keeping my head down**!* (I don't want to be noticed, or drawn into a contentious situation where ***I*** might be come a victim).

Comment: I think we'd need more context.  My first thought was that it might mean they find the current situation frightening.

Comment: Whoever is voting to reopen this, please leave a comment as to why you believe it was closed in error, specifically, how this question could be answered with facts or citations.

Comment: @gotube This is like every other sentence or idiom that you don't find a meaning for in the internet, if I could find I wouldn't ask it here, so this isn't that off-topic, this is what refers to an English phrase or sentence that I don't understand as a non-native person. Am I wrong?

Comment: @user48 We agree that this is a good enough question, and it's on topic. However, if the expression you're asking about isn't common enough that anyone can give a clear factual answer about what it means --rather than the guesswork in the only answer so far-- then it should be closed. Guesses can happen in the comments or in chat, but not in Answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bed can be seen as a hiding place, a place of concealment. You hide under the bed (literally or metaphorically) when you feel scared/embarrassed/uncomfortable/exposed. It means there is something that made you feel this way, so we can rule out *I don't think about it*.

The cause of the concealment is usually given by the context.

Here are a few examples:

> I'm hiding under my bed because I am insecure about my body.
>
> I'm hiding under my bed because I fear for my life.
>
> I'm hiding under my bed because I am tired of all this scrutiny I am subjected to.

Comment: I think it might be worth pointing out that this is something that pets like dogs and cats do when they're scared.